# How to filter the additional model in DetailView?

Tags: python, django

```
class Source(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=150)`enter code here`
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Office_Phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Office phone number')
    Main_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    Contact_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    Contact_Phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Main Contact phone number')
    Billing_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    Billing_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    Billing_Phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Billing Contact phone number')
    Notes = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sources-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Rate(models.Model):
    Source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Report_Type = models.ForeignKey(ReportType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class SourceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Source
    template_name = 'intake/source_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'source'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SourceDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['rates'] = Rate.objects.all.filter(***not sure what to put here***)        
        return context
```

Would it be better to filter it in the Template or do it in the View? I am able to get results if I don't filter it and just use `Rate.objects.all()`, and then I filter it in my template. Just think there is a better way to do this.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want the related `Rate` objects?

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what I forgot to write. I want the related Rate relative to the pk send to the DetailView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just fetch the relation in reverse:

```
class SourceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Source
    template_name = 'intake/source_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'source'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SourceDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['rates'] = self.object.rate_set.all()
        return context
```

That being said, here it does not make much difference to make the query in the template, since there is only one object here, so there is no *N+1 problem*.

Comment: Worded like a charm. Thank you so much!